# Process ReliableTopic's RingBuffer in reverse order (newest to oldest)

Tags: hazelcast

I am using a ReliableTopic to replay the last 20000 events and all subsequent events.

First off, which I subscribe to the `ReliableTopic` using a `ReliableMessageListener`, I am returning `0` from the `retrieveInitialSequence()` method everytime. **Is this correct for what I am trying to achieve?**

When I subscribe to `ReliableTopic`, I would like process everything that is in its internal `RingBuffer` in reverse order, from newest to oldest. I can achieve this by buffering the first `InternalRingBuffer.size()` items and then reversing that list. This relies on being able to retrieve the size of the internal `RingBuffer` as it may not be full. However, when I call `InternalRingBuffer.size()` on a newly connected instance, despite there being items in the buffer, it is returning `0`. **Why is this and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a bug and I have created the following issue: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/14468